# How to apply groupby lambda function in Python?

Tags: python, r

I use R much but new to Python. Take the popular `iris` data for example,

```r
str(iris)
## 'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
##  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
##  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
##  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
##  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
##  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

my demo first in R is given as follow:

```r
dat = iris  #iris dataset in base R
names(dat) = c(paste0('x',1:4),'g') #rename columns
dat$g = as.numeric(dat$g) #re-coding 3-level factor 
dat[,1:4] = dat[,1:4]*10 #enlarge x1-x4 values; just a test!
dim(dat)
## [1] 150   5
head(dat) #g=group, 3-level: 1,2,3
##   x1 x2 x3 x4 g
## 1 51 35 14  2 1
## 2 49 30 14  2 1
## 3 47 32 13  2 1
## 4 46 31 15  2 1
## 5 50 36 14  2 1
## 6 54 39 17  4 1

by(dat[,-5],dat[,5],nrow) #row size for each group; n_i
## dat[, 5]: 1
## [1] 50
## ------------------------------------------------------------ 
## dat[, 5]: 2
## [1] 50
## ------------------------------------------------------------ 
## dat[, 5]: 3
## [1] 50

by(dat[,-5],dat[,5],colMeans) #mean vector for data in each group; \bar{x}_i
## dat[, 5]: 1
##    x1    x2    x3    x4 
## 50.06 34.28 14.62  2.46 
## ------------------------------------------------------------ 
## dat[, 5]: 2
##    x1    x2    x3    x4 
## 59.36 27.70 42.60 13.26 
## ------------------------------------------------------------ 
## dat[, 5]: 3
##    x1    x2    x3    x4 
## 65.88 29.74 55.52 20.26 

m = dat[,-5] |> colMeans(); m  #mean vector for whole data; \bar{x}
##      x1       x2       x3       x4 
## 58.43333 30.57333 37.58000 11.99333 

# by(dat[,-5],dat[,5],cov) #covariance matrix for data in each group

H = by(dat[,-5],dat[,5],function(x) nrow(x)*tcrossprod(colMeans(x)-m) ) |> Reduce(f="+") ; H
##           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
## [1,]  6321.213 -1995.267 16524.84  7127.933
## [2,] -1995.267  1134.493 -5723.96 -2293.267
## [3,] 16524.840 -5723.960 43710.28 18677.400
## [4,]  7127.933 -2293.267 18677.40  8041.333

E = by(dat[,-5],dat[,5],function(x)(nrow(x)-1)*cov(x)) |> Reduce(f="+"); E
##         x1      x2      x3     x4
## x1 3895.62 1363.00 2462.46 564.50
## x2 1363.00 1696.20  812.08 480.84
## x3 2462.46  812.08 2722.26 627.18
## x4  564.50  480.84  627.18 615.66
```

which match the following manual results very well!

[image]

Then I want to **translate** R to Python. Surely, I can do it in Python in a ugly way, i.e, separating the  data one by one then integrating them. However, I want realize it in Python using a advanced way via `groupby lambda function`. I tried my best as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris() #iris dataset in sklearn for python
dat = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data*10, columns=[f'x{i}' for i in range(1,5)] ) #same treatment as in R
dat["g"] = iris.target+1 #re-coding 3-level factor 
dat.shape
## (150, 5)
dat.head() #g=group, 3-level: 1,2,3
##      x1    x2    x3   x4  g
## 0  51.0  35.0  14.0  2.0  1
## 1  49.0  30.0  14.0  2.0  1
## 2  47.0  32.0  13.0  2.0  1
## 3  46.0  31.0  15.0  2.0  1
## 4  50.0  36.0  14.0  2.0  1

dat.groupby('g').size()
## g
## 1    50
## 2    50
## 3    50
## dtype: int64

dat.groupby('g').mean() #mean vector for data in each group; \bar{x}_i
##       x1     x2     x3     x4
## g
## 1  50.06  34.28  14.62   2.46
## 2  59.36  27.70  42.60  13.26
## 3  65.88  29.74  55.52  20.26

m = dat.iloc[:,:-1].mean(); m #mean vector for whole data; \bar{x}
## x1    58.433333
## x2    30.573333
## x3    37.580000
## x4    11.993333
## dtype: float64

# dat.groupby('g').cov()

H = dat.groupby('g').apply(lambda x: np.size(x)*(x.mean()-m)@(x.mean()-m).T).agg(sum,axis=0); H
E = dat.groupby('g').apply(lambda x: (np.size(x)-1)*np.cov(x)).agg(sum,axis=0); E
```

So far so good, **except the last two lines**; i.e., wrong outputs of `H` and `E` in Python! Any help?

Comment: I'm sure this is doable in Numpy, but first you need to explain your notation.  What is ni in the first equation.  What does the "prime" mean in the equation for H and E?

Comment: @FrankYellin  The "prime" in the equation for H and E  means `the matrix & vector transpose symbol`! As shown in `head(dat)` of R and `dat.head()` of Python,  `x1 x2 x3 x4` means `Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width` and `g` means `Species` @FrankYellin

Comment: I re-edit my codes by adding detailed comments to make it clear this time @FrankYellin